# codeigniter database array parsing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter

I am very new to code igniter so i may be doing this wrong but whatever. I am trying to display a database but the problem is there are multiple tables and each one varies in number of columns and column names.

```
foreach ($database as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

This prints off the entire array in a very sloppy way. I can parse out values if i have column names but since they vary, I am struggling to resolve a way to parse it.

example of the array (with 5 columns, ID, Brand, Model, Tested and Comment)

```
Array ( [ID] => 3 [Brand] => IBM [Model] => Thinkcentre 8215-E9U [Tested] => 1 [Comment] => ) 
Array ( [ID] => 1 [Brand] => MGP [Model] => Thinkcentre 8183-T6U [Tested] => 1 [Comment] => ) 
Array ( [ID] => 2 [Brand] => IBM [Model] => Thinkcentre 8215-22U [Tested] => 1 [Comment] => ) 
Array ( [ID] => 4 [Brand] => IBM [Model] => Thinkcentre 8215-W97 [Tested] => 1 [Comment] => )
```

Model

```
public function select_videocards() {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_videocards');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Controller

```
 $table = NULL;

    if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') { // POST has been received
            $table = $this->input->post('table');
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
    $data['table'] = $table;

    if($table!="select" AND $table!=NULL) {
        echo $table;
        $data['database'] = $this->Inventory_model->$table();
    }
```

Comment: How many databases you have set in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` file?

Comment: `there are multiple databases` what exactly do you mean by this? Aswell do you mean actual databases or tables? Would u mind showing the query you are running too. That way you would get better help.

Comment: Yes my mistake there are multiple tables not multiple databases. Also, I added the model and controller to the post above for reference now.

Answer (score 0):

I just made more functions in my controller as wrapper functions and then made a new page for each table. worked perfectly.